# Why [null, undefined, []] == ",," returns true

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison-operators, coercion

I know that abstract comparison will convert LHS to String and `String([null, undefined, []])` will result to `',,'`.

But `String(null)` is `'null'` and `String(undefined)` is `'undefined'`. So how `String([null, undefined, []])` is `',,'`?

Comment: I like the question but can you please format it a bit? It's hard to read.

Comment: Also, the title and post body seem to be asking different questions. Nonempty strings are truthy, array objects are truthy, and arrays simply stringify differently than `undefined` or `null` does so I don't find the behavior surprising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because.

1. That's how `==` is defined https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison See step 11: `If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String, Number, BigInt, or Symbol, return the result of the comparison ? ToPrimitive(x) == y.`
2. Then `ToPrimitive` happens: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive
3. Then `OrdinaryToPrimitive` happens: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive which calls `Array.prototype.toString`
4. For arrays it calls `Array.prototype.join(arr)` See https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.tostring
5. That's how `Array.prototype.join` is implemented: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.join, the most important steps:

```
Repeat, while k < len,

* If k > 0, set R to the string-concatenation of R and sep.
* Let element be ? Get(O, ! ToString(k)).
* If element is undefined or null, let next be the empty String; otherwise, let next be ? ToString(element).
* Set R to the string-concatenation of R and next.
* Set k to k + 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

zerkms's answer is an excellent one if you want the detailed specs. In plainer language, it's like this:

1. The String constructor basically converts the parameter you pass in into a string.
2. In this case, the parameter is an Array (created via `[...]` syntax).
3. Converting an Array to a string is done by making a comma-separated list of string representations of the values inside it, with one interesting caveat: Even though `undefined` and `null` would normally be converted into `"undefined"` and `"null"`, [the spec for Array.prototype.join](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.join) referenced in zerkms's answer specifies that it will use an empty string instead of doing a normal string conversion.
4. The third item in your array is an empty array (again created via `[]` syntax). Because there's nothing to separate with commas, this also produces an empty string when converted to a string.

So you end up with and empty string followed by a comma, followed by another empty string, followed by a comma, followed by another empty string. Hence, `",,"`.

Another way to look at it is that you're basically calling:

```
[undefined, null, []].join(",")
```

... which treats `undefined` and `null` values as if they were empty strings.

Comment: Right, it's a spec re-wording, my apologies, removed my other comment

Comment: @zerkms: Ah, indeed, right you are. I'll fix that...

Comment: What I mean is - it's hard to phrase it both "understandable" and "not too wrong" simultaneously :-)

Comment: I totally get what you mean. Hopefully my re-wording is less wrong and still mostly understandable.

Comment: Yep, now it's much better, sorry again for nit-picking

Answer (score 1):

> I know that abstract comparison will convert LHS to String and
> String([null, undefined, []]) will result to ',,'.
>
> But String(null) is 'null' and String(undefined) is 'undefined'. So
> how String([null, undefined, []]) is ',,'?

Why are you thinking that `func([x, y, z])` should equal to `func(x) + func(y) + func(z)` ?

See these examples:

```
String([1, 2]); // "1,2"
String([null]); // ""
String([undefined]); // ""
String([[]]); // ""
String([1, null, undefined]); // "1,,"

// In same way 

String([null, undefined, []]); // ",,"
```

Try to relate these examples with your question.